# I want add images as i move the mouse in a kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm developing a kivy app, for desktop, i separated some goals to archive, but struggling in the fist one, i need to drawn a image as i move the mouse when it's pressed, but right now, only show a image when is touch down event and at end of the move event

here is my code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import *

kv = """
<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        
        # on_touch_move: print_cordinates(root.touch)
        # on_touch_move: add_images(root.touch)
        on_touch_down: root.on_touch_down_2(args[1])
        on_touch_move: root.on_touch_move_2(args[1])
    
<Image>:
    size: self.texture_size
"""

brush_size = 10


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def on_touch_down_2(self, touch):
        self.add_widget(Image(source='img/brush/square.png',
                              pos=(touch.x - 10/2, touch.y - 10/2)))

    def on_touch_move_2(self, touch):
        self.add_widget(Image(source='img/brush/square.png',
                              pos=(touch.x - 10/2, touch.y - 10/2)))



class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


MainApp().run()
```

the image i use is simple 10px x 10px green square(the color don't matter now)

Comment: I added `size_hint: None, None` to your `<Image>` rule. But when I run your code, it adds an `Image` when I press the mouse, and it adds more `Images` as I move the mouse (with button held down). Is that what you want?

Comment: i thanks for the reply, sorry i implemented it as i thought to be but not achieved the desired result can share the modified code to i see if made some mistakes, my goal was to make something like the touch tracer example

Comment: It appears to me that you succeeded. The code performs similar to the touch tracer example.